# Windows Phone 8.1 Application Picker

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

How to display the Application picker in WIndows Phone 8.1 for a file through code? Currently I am using `DisplayApplicationPicker = true` but it is not working. Can Anyone Please give me a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Your where almost there:

```
// Set the option to show the picker
      var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
      options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
```

Source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcheroptions.displayapplicationpicker.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
filePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

// Filter to include a sample subset of file types
filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

filePicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
```